# How to convert a flat data collection into hierarchical one?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a flat data in the form of collection as follows:

```
historyId   documentId   statusId
612         2            1
612         3            2
612         4            5
612         2            4
```

When the above data is populated into the colloection of myClassFlat, it will have four members in the collection

```
class myClassFlat{
    public int historyId {get; set;}
    public int documentId { get; set;}
    public int statusId {get; set;}
}
```

I want to convert to heirarchical data into another collection as follows, such that the duplicate values in documentId are groupedby and the statusId is loaded into an array within the class:

```
historyId   documentId   statusId
612         2            1, 4
612         3            2
612         4            5
```

So when the data is populated into a collection of the following myClassHierarchical, it will have only three members, since the two values of statusId, 1 and 4, will be populated into the `int[]` statusId of the class

```
class myClassHierarchical{
    public int historyId {get; set;}
    public int documentId { get; set;}
    public int[] statusId {get; set;}
}
```

I tried to first find out unique members of the collection by documentId using Linq and then loop through the non unique members and create a list of the classes and populate the int[] with statusId, but couldn't make it to work.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `GroupBy`? I can't see any hierarchy here.

Comment: It is a list. From the original list I have to create another list so that documentId is unique and any duplicate document Id's should have the corresponding statusId to be converted into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to group by two fields:

```
var list = new List<myClassFlat>
    {
        new myClassFlat() { historyId = 612, documentId = 2, statusId = 1},
        new myClassFlat() { historyId = 612, documentId = 3, statusId = 2},
        new myClassFlat() { historyId = 612, documentId = 4, statusId = 5},
        new myClassFlat() { historyId = 612, documentId = 2, statusId = 4},
    };

var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.historyId, x.documentId })
                 .Select(g => new myClassHierarchical()
                     {
                         historyId = g.Key.historyId,
                         documentId = g.Key.documentId,
                         statusId = g.Select(x => x.statusId).ToArray()
                     });
```

Comment: Why the downvote here? This does exactly what the question asks for?

Comment: I can't imagine why you got the downvote. I upvoted you because this was the most straight-forward answer that did exactly what the OP wanted.